# Using slashes in tel: URIs

Tags: cross-browser, uri, tel

It's pretty clear that the *correct* way to link to a phone number from HTML is with a URI like `tel:2065551212`.  However many browsers also accept telephone URIs with slashes, a la `tel://2065551212` even though this is AFAICT not allowed by the relevant RFC ([3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966)).

So, my question is this: why do some people recommend using slashes?  Is it just a bad habit from http URIs?

Or... Were there actually some early mobile browsers that did not properly recognize `tel:` links without the slashes?  I have read at least one blogger indicating that this is the case, which is a poor but understand excuse for doing so.  Can anybody provide an example where `tel://###` would work but `tel:###` would not?